# How can I join on a row to get back to the first relevant row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been searching on the net for an answer to a SQL related question. I hope anyone can help me out.

Table1

| Item |
| --- |
| ABC4 |

Table 2

| Previous-Item | New-Item |
| --- | --- |
| ABC1 | ABC2 |
| ABC1 | ABC3 |
| ABC2 | ABC3 |
| ABC3 | ABC4 |

I want to join Table 1 (Item) to Table 2 (New-Item) and get all the previous items (back from ABC4 to ABC1. Combinations are possible in the data.
Sometimes an item can only be backtracked from 4 to 1 and sometimes directly.
This theoretically could go to infinite. So I am looking for a situation how I can make a loop in a join.

My query right now is:

```
SELECT 
T1.Item, 
T3.Previous-Item 
FROM Table1 T1 (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 (NOLOCK) ON T1.Item = T2.Previous-Item
LEFT LOOP JOIN Table2 T3(NOLOCK) ON T2.Item = T3.Previous-Item
```

UPDATE:

The expected result would be:

| Item | Previous-Item |
| --- | --- |
| ABC4 | ABC3 |
| ABC4 | ABC2 |
| ABC4 | ABC1 |

Comment: Can you provide some data samples and their expected result ?. I guess you want a join with a recursive CTE. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have updated the question

Comment: Is there a reason you're spamming the `NOLOCK` hint? Why aren't you changing the isolation level when you use it against every table?

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). And if you know and accept the risks, AT LEAST use current syntax and not deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [recursive CTE](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/) can do what your LOOP JOIN intends :

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( item varchar(20) )
CREATE TABLE Table2 ( previous_item varchar(20), new_item varchar(20) )

INSERT INTO Table1 (item) 
            values ('ABC4')
INSERT INTO Table2 (previous_item, new_item)
            values ('ABC1', 'ABC2'),
                   ('ABC1', 'ABC3'),
                   ('ABC2', 'ABC3'),
                   ('ABC3', 'ABC4')

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

WITH resursive_cte as (
  select item, item as previous_item, cast(null as varchar(20)) as new_item
  from Table1 -- Anchor (initial records)
  union all
  select recursive_cte.item, Table2.previous_item, Table2.new_item
  from resursive_cte -- Recursive records
       inner join Table2 on Table2.new_item = recursive_cte.previous_item
)          
select distinct item, previous_item
from resursive_cte
where new_item is not null
```

You can see it working here : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71277cdf19635e473803292f1e0c5ee4)

**PS:** I have included a `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;` command, as Larnu has recommended, so you don't need to use the NOLOCK hint manually on every table if you want to include dirty reads.